# Why is cmake not finding an installed package?

Tags: package-management, make, cmake, makefile, bzip2

I'm trying to build [this repo](https://github.com/ANNetGPGPU/ANNetGPGPU) for neural networks implemented in CUDA.

I've followed the instructions in that link and performed the following actions on a shell:

```
git clone https://github.com/ANNetGPGPU/ANNetGPGPU.git
cd ANNetGPGPU
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. && make
```

However, when I write that last line, the following error is returned:

```
CMake Error at /home/iibm/Documents/martins/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/iibm/Documents/martins/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/iibm/Documents/martins/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBZip2.cmake:62 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/iibm/Documents/martins/ANNetGPGPU/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

But bzip2 is definitely installed, as `bzip2 --version` returns:

```
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.

   Copyright (C) 1996-2010 by Julian Seward.
```

So how can I fix this issue, and why is it happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you build software that uses libraries such as bzip2, you need to have the -dev package installed, which includes the header files (`*.h`) needed by the compiler and the library files needed by the linker.

In your case, for bzip2, on Ubuntu, the name of the package with the files you need is `libbz2-dev`, so you can solve this problem by installing this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clear and it indeed solved the problem.